# instances of the class Class

Tags: java, class, reflection

I have a couple of questions about instances of the class Class

1) Do I understand correctly that say for the class Dog there is only one instance of the class Class. In other words, given the following lines

```
Dog dog1 = new Dog();
Dog dog2 = new Dog();

Class dog1Class = dog1.getClass();
Class dog2Class = dog2.getClass();
Class dogClass = Dog.class;
```

there is only one instance of the class Class - `Class<Dog>`.

If you compare these references with ==, you get that they are the same object.

The question exactly is, will getClass and static .class always return the same instance during one execution of a main method?

2) When exactly are these instances created?

Comment: If you have multiple classloaders, things get more complicated...

Comment: Pretty good question actually and as @Oli already said, multiple classloaders and especially dynamic loading might throw a whole collection of spanners in the works. Really curious to see what the answer really is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> will getClass and static .class always return the same instance

No, not exactly. `dog.getClass()` method returns the runtime type of dog.

Consider the following classes:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
```

And then in main method:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();     
System.out.println(dog.getClass());   // Prints class Dog
System.out.println(Animal.class);     // Prints class Animal
```

---

> When exactly are these instances created?

When the class is first loaded by JVM. From documentation of [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.

**For detailed study:**

- [JVM Specification - Loading, Linking, and Initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html)
- [JLS - Loading of Classes and Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `Class` instance representing a class; you can rest assured that it is the same instance, no matter how you get it.

For example, a static synchronized method uses that exact instance for locking; apparently it won't work if there are multiple instances. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6

Comment: Exactly)) I didn't think about it